# Why are the absolute magnitudes in M5 galaxy so puny?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, star-clusters

Wikipedia gives the following as the HR diagram for M5:
[image]

The stars at the base of the red giant branch have absolute visual magnitudes of 15?  That seems way, way too dim.  The sun's absolute magnitude according to wikipedia is 4.83, although it doesn't state in what filter that measurement was taken.  What is going on here?

Comment: Since the stars in M5 are all at the same distance they might have plotted apparent magnitude?

Comment: Pretty sure they mistook absolute magnitude for apparent magnitude here. Also, for future reference, this probably would be better answered on Astronomy SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a simple mistake. According to [Layden et al. (2005)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0506727), the distance to M5 is 7.76 kpc and has a V-band extinction of 0.11 mag. You need to subtract 14.56 mag from the y-axis to get the absolute magnitude.

As an aside, I did eventually find the incorrectly labelled diagram [here](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:M5_colour_magnitude_diagram.png). The "author", *Lithopsian*, gives no reference to where the data came from and claims it as their own work! *Caveat emptor*. I would stick to diagrams published in reputable journals.